# indefinite number of chars matching against a regex

Tags: javascript, regex, reactjs, text-mask

I'm looking for a way to create a mask that would accept a set of an indefinite number of characters that should match against a regular expression.

It seems that I could achieve that with [text-mask](https://text-mask.github.io/text-mask/) library but by using an array I could pass only a definite number of characters. It says in the docs I could use a function (instead of an array) as the mask and I'm given some properties I could use but apparently I can't use a regex then.

I've tried this but it doesn't seem to work:

```
<MaskedInput mask={(value) => value.split().map(() => /[a-zA-Z0-9]*/)} >
</MaskedInput>
```

Comment: What have you tried? please show a minimal example so we can help.

Comment: thanks, just added it

Comment: well you are returning an array.... my guess it wants a string back. `.map(...).join('')`

Comment: according to the docs it expects a mask array but it's kind of unclear: https://github.com/text-mask/text-mask/blob/master/componentDocumentation.md#readme